# how to handle "Launch Application" pop up window in firefox using autoIT

Tags: autoit

I am testing a webpage (in firefox browser) using selenium where there is a scenario which opens windows pop-up which I need to control(handle) using AutoIT.

I have tried the following code but it did not work.

```
WinWaitActive("Launch Application","Launch Application",10)
ControlCommand("Launch Application", "Launch Application","","Check")
ControlClick("Launch Application","Launch Application","","left")
```

**How do I do the following using the autoIT**

1. Tick the checkbox "Remember my choice for xauthorforexcel links"
2. Click on the "Open Link" button

   OR
3. Click on the "Cancel" Button.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

**AutoIT Window Info is as follows:**

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Launch Application
Class:  MozillaDialogClass
Position:   476, 317
Size:   328, 350
Style:  0x16CC0084
ExStyle:    0x00000101
Handle: 0x00000000001409A6

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  
Instance:   
ClassnameNN:    
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   
ID: 
Text:   
Position:   
Size:   
ControlClick Coords:    
Style:  
ExStyle:    
Handle: 

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   731, 632
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0x85B3DF

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a window with both Title and Text as "Launch Application" but the window only has that for the Title.  Change the WinWaitActive() to

```
WinWaitActive("Launch Application", "",10)
```

If that doesn't help, it is possible the window is not active. If so, use:

```
Local $hWnd = WinWait("Launch Application","",10)
WinActivate($hWnd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,using `Local $hWnd = WinWait("Launch Application","",10)`
`WinActivate($hWnd)` I am able to get the control(Focus) to the window but how do I tick the check box and click on "Open Link" or "Cancel" button.

Comment: Use the [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) function to mimic the same keystrokes you would if you were manually doing this.  Have you seen the [Tutorials](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/)? They should have examples of this.  Basically Send("!r") is the same as Alt+R which should toggle the check in the box since the R is underlined. Send("{ENTER}") should accept and Send("{ESCAPE}") should Cancel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Really appreciate your help.